# What does the yarn progress indicator represent?

Tags: yarnpkg

When I'm installing a project, I see some huge numbers in the progress indicator and it takes forever to install:

```
281929/413770
```

However, it doesn't appear that my project has 413770 dependencies.

```
cat yarn.lock | grep '^[^ ]' | wc -l
1257
```

Any ideas what those numbers are in the progress indicator and why might be making this install so slow?

Comment: I thought about dependencies, and I guess it's possible, but that would mean an average of 329 indirect dependencies per direct dependency...

Answer (score 0):

Dependencies have other dependencies, etc. I would imagine it's a total number of the modules pulled from the server.

Answer (score 0):

As @Paul states, every package might have its own dependencies.
You should be able to see a log of all your packages by using:

```
yarn list
```

which by default shows every dependency.
Also your `package.json` should list all of these dependencies.

Keep in mind that they are [multiple types of dependencies](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/dependency-types/).
Some of them (e.g `devDependencies`) are required only in the development workflow so they only are installed locally in your machine.

About those big numbers, I saw them while installing and asked myself a couple of times too, but my personal guess is: they are the number/amount of the chunks.
Chunks are [buffers](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) (a buffer stores binary data). I have no evidence to support this and I am not entirely sure. But this is my guess.

By using `yarn install --verbose`, you should be able to see in greater detail what happens when installing those packages.

Regarding the slow install, I think it's safe to say that Yarn is faster than NPM (shouldn't be opinion-based to say that). So I would advise keeping Yarn.
You could try to run:

```
yarn install --flat
```

which will only allow one version for each package and might save some space/time during the next package installs.
You will only need to run it once as the changes will be saved in your `package.json` under the resolutions. [Link of the docs](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install/#toc-yarn-install-flat)

As a last resort, when time is key, we might want to suppress the console logs and it should be slightly faster:

```
yarn install --silent
```

Of course, the times that it takes to install depends also on the computer that you use.

Comment: This is a post with relevant information, but it does't answer the part of question I care about: what does this number mean?